# java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem for singelton class

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I have a program with two classes that declared as singeltone classes.
When I am trying to run the program I am getting a java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem in the line that getting the instance of the singeltone class and I don't understand why.

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 

    at Model.Recommender.getInstance(Recommender.java:22)
    at Model.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:21)
    at Controller.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:69)
```

The error line in the Recommender class:

```
public static Recommender getInstance() {
```

And the class declared this way:

```
public class Recommender {

    private static Recommender recommender; //a recommender
    private HashSet<Reader> libraryReaders; //a hash set of all of the library readers

    //constructor to initialize the fields
    private Recommender() 
    {
        libraryReaders = new HashSet<Reader>();
    }

    //method to make the class a singleton class
    public static Recommender getInstance() {
        if(recommender == null) //check that a instance of this class doesn't exist
        {
            recommender = new Recommender(); //creates a new instance
        }
        return recommender; //return the instance that was created
    }
}
```

The error line in the library class:

```
private static Recommender recommender = Recommender.getInstance();
```

And the class declared this way:

```
public class Library {

    private static Library library; //a library
    private static Recommender recommender = Recommender.getInstance();
    private HashSet<Reader> readers;
    private HashSet<Author> authors;
    private HashSet<LibraryItem> items;

    //constructor to initialize the fields
    private Library() {
        readers = new HashSet<Reader>();
        authors = new HashSet<Author>();
        items = new HashSet<LibraryItem>();
    }

    //method to make the class a singleton class
    public static Library getInstance() {
        if(library == null) //check that a instance of this class doesn't exist
        {
            library = new Library(); //creates a new instance
        }
        return library; //return the instance that was created
    }
}
```

The error in the Main class:

```
LibrarySys = Library.getInstance();
```

I am creating an instance of recommender in the library class and an instance of library in the main class. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Your method name is `Recommender.getInstance()` and you call `Recommender.getInstance1()`. Just a typo error I think ;)

Comment: I changed that and still get the same error

Comment: @Daniel16 I am not able to reproduce your issue, I copied the same code and I didn't get something. could you please add more info like packages and imports names?

Comment: Note: 'Unresolved compilation problem' means the code does not compile correctly. You can't run code cleanly while Eclipse is showing errors in the code.

Answer (score 1):

the code you posted is fine. As for your compilation errors, you'll have to check your imports, other classes that are not written in this code such as Reader, Author, and LibraryItem. are you using external JARs in your application? maybe your classpath is the problem.

Also, in 2019, your Recommender singleton class can be written simply as an enum without the need for the getInstance() method (which is not thread-safe anyway) as such:

```
public enum Recommender {

INSTANCE;

private HashSet<Reader> libraryReaders;

private Recommender() {
    libraryReaders = new HashSet<Reader>();
}

//getters and setters... //
```

}

and using it is as simple as writing Recommender.INSTANCE without the need to initialize anything.

Answer (score 0):

What is LibrarySys?
Shouldn't it be

```
Library myLibrary = Library.getInstance();
```